# Ajax request progress status

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest

I am having an ajax request which calls a controller method in .net MVC framework.

The process is a time consuming one and there are lot of intermediate process happening i want the user to be posted with the current status(not percentage of completion).

Is there any way to accomplish this other than splitting the process into multiple ajax request.